# Calculate time difference and sum the results in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array contains time data in string, like this:

```php
$time = [
    "10:05:32",
    "11:03:43",
    "13:43:16",
    "10:17:21"
];
```

Now I want to calculate `$time[x] - 10:00:00`, and sum all the results: `00:05:32 + 01:03:43 + 03:43:16 + 00:17:21` (=5:09:52)

I have read some reference in php.net, but everything is about date, there is no a solution for simple time calculation?

Comment: Well that's not really an issue: `date` stores both date and time, thus set all the given times on january 1, 2000 or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is covert them to timestamp first, then map the differences then sum them up. Like this:

```
$diff = '10:00:00';
$time = ["10:05:32", "11:03:43", "13:43:16", "10:17:21"];
$time = array_map(function($t) use ($diff){
    return strtotime($t) - strtotime($diff);
}, $time);

$time = gmdate('H:i:s', array_sum($time));
echo $time; // 05:09:52
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below working code

```
$time = array("10:05:32", "11:03:43", "13:43:16", "10:17:21");
$seconds=0;
foreach ($time as $value){
    list($h,$m,$s)=split(":",$value);       
    $seconds=$seconds+($s+($h*3600)+($m*60))-36000;
}
$output = gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
echo $output;
```

//output is 05:09:52

Answer (score 0):

```
 function dateDifference($startDate, $endDate) 
        { 
            $startDate = strtotime($startDate); 
            $endDate = strtotime($endDate); 
            if ($startDate === false || $startDate < 0 || $endDate === false || $endDate < 0 || $startDate > $endDate) 
                return false; 

            $years = date('Y', $endDate) - date('Y', $startDate); 

            $endMonth = date('m', $endDate); 
            $startMonth = date('m', $startDate); 

            // Calculate months 
            $months = $endMonth - $startMonth; 
            if ($months <= 0)  { 
                $months += 12; 
                $years--; 
            } 
            if ($years < 0) 
                return false; 

            // Calculate the days 
                        $offsets = array(); 
                        if ($years > 0) 
                            $offsets[] = $years . (($years == 1) ? ' year' : ' years'); 
                        if ($months > 0) 
                            $offsets[] = $months . (($months == 1) ? ' month' : ' months'); 
                        $offsets = count($offsets) > 0 ? '+' . implode(' ', $offsets) : 'now'; 

                        $days = $endDate - strtotime($offsets, $startDate); 
                        $days = date('z', $days);    

            return array($years, $months, $days); 
        }
```

This accepts any of the [formats listed on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php), including hour minute seconds, which is what you appear to have... Hope that helps.