# Calculeted time adding together in php (H:i:s)

Tags: php

I have a query which returns me some data.

```
//I loop through the query's result and write all data out

while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['place'] . '|';
    echo $row['gets_busy'] . '|';
    echo $row['gets_empty '] . '|';
    echo $row['time_between'] . '|';
    echo "<br>";
}

ROOM01|2021-03-05 12:02:56|2021-03-05 12:04:02|00:01:06|
ROOM01|2021-03-05 12:05:42|2021-03-05 12:07:48|00:02:06|
ROOM01|2021-03-05 12:07:48|2021-03-05 12:12:54|00:05:06|
ROOM02|2021-03-05 12:15:54|2021-03-05 12:17:00|00:01:06|
ROOM02|2021-03-05 12:17:01|2021-03-05 12:23:17|00:05:16|
ROOM02|2021-03-05 12:23:59|2021-03-05 12:25:45|00:01:46|
```

I want something to write for the user like:

```
ROOM01 was busy for -> 00:08:18 during 2021-03-05
ROOM02 was busy for -> 00:08:08 during 2021-03-05
```

Can this be accomplished by PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate time difference and sum the results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321495/calculate-time-difference-and-sum-the-results-in-php)

Comment: There's modification to be made compared to the linked question, but the gist is there - summing an array of differences. One definitive improvement would be placing all this data into an actual array, instead of outputting directly in the loop that reads from the database, since you need to perform more than one action over the data.

Comment: The suggested answer postet by @El_Vanja is outdated. Since PHP 5 there is a DateTime class in PHP, which can be used to calculate time differences in a one liner. No need for string to time comparisons and follow up functionality anymore.

Comment: Have a look at DateTime::diff() https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Or do you just want literally printed "Room X was busy for {value from database} during {value from database}"?

Comment: I want to calculate them, bc there are more than 2 rooms which I want to show.
So I want to sum them by Roomname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group into another array, by using the places and date as keys.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $place = $row['place']; // shortcut
    $start = strtotime($row['gets_busy']); // start timestamp
    $stop  = strtotime($row['gets_empty']); // end timestamp
    $time  = $stop - $start; // duration in seconds
    $date  = date('Y-m-d', $start); // date for grouping

    // group by place and date
    if (!isset($data[$place][$date])) {
        $data[$place][$date] = 0; // init with 0
    }
    $data[$place][$date] += $time; // add time.
}

// now, display data :
foreach ($data as $place => $dates) {
    echo $place . ':<br>';
    foreach ($dates as $date => $duration) {
        $interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$duration.'S');
        echo ' -> ' . $date . ' : ' . $interval->format('%h:%i:%s') . '<br>';
    }
}
```